# Flutter Pub Get Issue Permission Denied

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, permissions

I use MacOS and whenever I run the flutter pub get command this error occurs

```
Cannot open file, path = '.dart_tool/package_config.json' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```